# How to override react's index.d.ts?

Tags: reactjs, svg, typescript, typescript-typings

I am building a React client using Typescript (TSX). In my webpage, I want to build an SVG using React's SVG API. It works, but Typescript is complaining about it. Here's a concrete example taken from one of my TSX files:

```
<marker id="my-marker" refX="0.0" refY="0.0" orient="auto">
  ... children ...
</marker>
```

Here, Typescript complains that `refX`, `refY` and `orient` are not part of `SVGProps` (defined in the typings file `index.d.ts` of the `react` module), even though every relevant browser interprets them correctly. They are also defined in the [SVG Standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/svg-markers/#MarkerElement) and mentioned in the [SVG documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/SVG/Element/marker).

How do I go about this situation? Should I override the `index.d.ts` file of React to add the missing properties to `SVGProps`, and if so, how do I do that? My guess is that `SVGProps` is simply describing an older version of SVG where these properties did not exist. But I need to use these properties, and I don't want to see this error over and over again in each Typescript compile.

Comment: What version of typings are you using? 15.0 seems to have `refX` and `refY`: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/react/index.d.ts#L2304-L2305

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, according to my `package.json` I am using react 15.4.x... Oh but I see that my react typings are still at 0.14.55. Maybe that's the cause!

Still, for future reference: how would you go about this when there is no update to the library that happens to fix the issue?

Comment: Fork and fix the issue, create a pull request; use your fork until the pull request is merged.